# Spring MVC- Hibernate: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I’m working on a maven sample project where in I use MySQL, Spring and Hibernate. 
I created a database using terminal in my mac. Used the following commands to log into mysql and create database and tables.

```
    $ sudo -s
    Password:
    bash-3.2# mysql -u root -p
    Enter password:
```

In my jdbc.properties file, I have this:

```
    jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample
    jdbc.username = root    
    jdbc.password = root
    hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    hibernate.show_sql = true
    hibernate.format_sql = true
```

On launching the url, I get to see this,

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection


exception:
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

root cause:
    org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

root cause:
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

root cause:
    java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root '@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I’m not familiar using terminal and the commands. Can anyone let me know what is the issue here and what should be the jdbc.username and jdbc.password. I don’t have a Query Browser, I’ve gotta use only the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I guess privileges are missing for "root@localhost"

Here are the steps to grant privileges

```
$ sudo -s
  Password:
  bash-3.2# mysql -u root -p
  Enter password:
```

After you are logged in, grant privileges to root@localhost

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Tried it. Still get to see the same error, java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root '@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Can you share output of "select version();" & "SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';"

Comment: 5.6.16 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ‘password’ WITH GRANT OPTION 
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: ‘password’ is this what you have in jdbc.properties?

Comment: jdbc.properties has "root" as the password and grant output has "password" as the password. Can you check?

Comment: in jdbc.properties I have 'root' as username and password. You had asked me to grant priviledges and I did with password 'root' again. But when I checked output for this, SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost'; I got the output as, GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: I really don't think it has anything to do with the permissions as such. That would happen in the later stages of the code. This error mainly occurs when your MYSQL password is either wrong/expired. Make sure you are providing the correct password and username. Secondly, make sure you are reading the password and username for the correct location..

Comment: @Karthik : Access denied errors can happen when PRIVILEGES are missing/incorrect.